# Probability that some that m points are probable given the probability of subsets.

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, graph-theory

Working in a problem in analysis I came across this combinatorial/discrete probability question. I would appreciate if someone knows how to approach this problem or knows if this problem is related with something else.

Let $X=\left\{  x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{N}\right\}  $ and $m<M.$ We denote the
subsets of size $m$ as $S_{1},...,S_{\binom{N}{m}}.$ Assume $P$ is a real
function such that $\sum_{i=1}^{_{\binom{N}{m}}}P(S_{i})=1.$ Now we define
$p(x_{j})=\sum_{S_{i}\ni x_{j}}P(s_{i}).$

The question is does there exist $m$ points  $x\in X$ such that $p(x)\geq
m/N?$ (if it is not true what if we write $2^{-N/m}$ instead of $m/N$)

Comment: Given that this problem is inspired by probability, is $P$ really just real-valued or is it non-negative?

Comment: Yes non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{j=1}^{N}{p(x_j)} = \sum_{i=1}^{\binom{N}{m}}{m P(S_i)} = m.$$

The first equality is because each $P(S_i)$ appears in exactly $m$ of the $p(x_j)$ terms (since each $S_i$ has $m$ members).

Dividing both ends of the equation by $N$, we see the average of $p(x_j)$ is $\dfrac{m}{N}$. Therefore, for some $j,\; p(x_j) \geq \dfrac{m}{N}$.

**Edit #1**: A simple counterexample: $N=3, m=2, X=\{1,2,3\}$.

\begin{eqnarray*}
S_1 = \{1,2\} && P(S_1) = 1/2 \\
S_2 = \{1,3\} && P(S_2) = 1/2 \\
S_3 = \{2,3\} && P(S_3) = 0. \\
&& \\
\therefore  \frac{m}{N} = \frac{2}{3} &&\text{ but } p(1) = 1,\; p(2) = \frac{1}{2},\; p(3) = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

**Edit #2**: A more complete answer to the question of does there exist a given number of points $x$ such that $p(x) \geq $ some value.

Firstly, we know that the average of all the $p(x)$ is $\frac{m}{N}$ and also that numbers are in the interval $[0,1]$. If we arrange the $N$ $P(x)$ values in ascending order and they had the following values:

$$\underbrace{a,a,\ldots,a}_{N-k \text{ times}},\underbrace{1,1,\ldots,1}_{k \text{ times}}.$$

then we could say that there exists $k+1$ points $x$ with $p(x) \geq a$ for *any* arrangement where the numbers had that average and those upper and lower bounds.

Since the average is $\dfrac{m}{N}$, we must have $a = \dfrac{m-k}{N-k}$. This is as long as $k \leq m$, otherwise we get $a \lt 0$.

Note that such an arrangement is achievable in terms of the $P(S_i)$ values as follows. Assume $k \leq m$ and nominate a given $k$ elements of $X$. There are $\binom{N-k}{m-k}$ sets $S_i$ containing all $k$ nominated elements since we need to choose the remaining $m-k$ elements of $S_i$ from $N-k$ choices. Set $P(S_i) = \binom{N-k}{m-k}^{-1}$ for each of these. For all other $S_i$, set $P(S_i) = 0$. Then, if $x$ is one of the $k$ nominated elements, we have $p(x) = 1$. If $y$ is not one of the $k$ nominated elements, it appears in exactly $\binom{N-k-1}{m-k-1}$ of the $S_i$ with positive probability since such an $S_i$ contains the $k$ nominated elements and also $y$ and there are $\binom{N-k-1}{m-k-1}$ ways to choose the remaining $m-k-1$ elements. Therefore $p(y) = \binom{N-k-1}{m-k-1} \bigg/ \binom{N-k}{m-k} = \dfrac{m-k}{N-k}$. This completes the above arrangement.

$\\$

To address your particular question, setting $k=m-1$, we get $a = p(y) = \dfrac{m-(m-1)}{N-(m-1)} =\dfrac{1}{N-m+1}$. Therefore, we can say that, for any assignment of the $P(S_i)$ values, there exists $m$ points $x$ such that $p(x) \geq \dfrac{1}{N-m+1}$.

Comment: This shows there exists one point. I wanted to know if there exist m points with this property.

Comment: I think that it is possible to construct a counterexample. But by doing what you mentioned several times one can show there exists m/2 points with probability larger than m/2.

Comment: @Rob Sorry, I misread the question a little. I've added a counterexample showing that $m$ points don't necessarily exist. In your last comment, do you mean "... probability larger than m/N"?

Comment: @Rob I added a bit more to the answer. I hope it's useful.